# Send preformatted text in Skype

Tags: formatting, skype

Sometimes I send pieces of code using Skype. Very often the text is messed up with smileys, and some brackets show up doubled.

Can I somehow send text that will not be transformed? Something like `<pre>` in HTML.

EDIT ( 19 march 2015 ): In Win 8.1 Skype version 7.2.59.103 (for desktop) both [nesono's answer](https://superuser.com/a/806164/32497) and [Nishanth C's answer](https://superuser.com/a/848163/32497) are working.

Comment: You could disable smileys and suggest your recipient do the same.  It's not as nice as what you're asking for though.

Comment: For reference, [here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA3271/how-do-i-send-an-instant-message-in-skype-for-windows-desktop?q=chat+formatting#) is the official list of Skype formatting escapes, under **Formatting your instant messages**.

Comment: {code}print(":)");{code}

Comment: note, the opening {code} has to be at the beginning of a line

Comment: @IstvánZachar Skype formatting seems to have changed radically in the new Skype included as part of Windows 10 (I'm on Skype 12.7.597.0). I have asked a new question at [Do not insert emoticons into sent messages in Skype version 12](https://superuser.com/questions/1265799/do-not-insert-emoticons-into-sent-messages-in-skype-version-12)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In fact you can keep Skype from parsing the snippet for smileys. Just use two exclamation marks as the first line (rest empty) and paste your snippet afterwards.

Example:

`!!
call_function(0);
:)
(smoke)`

Apart from that, you can use decorations to post `*bold*`, `_italic_` or `~strikethrough~` text.

Comment: Skype for Windows (6.20.64.104) support that

Comment: You can also append "`!! ` " before the text to leave the text raw.
I don't like the extra line made from !!

Comment: You don't have to make a new line after !!, a blank space suffices.

E.g.: !! function foo() {};

Will output "function foo() {};", without the exclamation marks and the space. No new line. (Skype for OS X, 7.14 301)

Comment: Does not work on Skype Linux 4.3.0.37.

Comment: Does not work with Skype for Linux Beta 5.4.0.1 and xml

Comment: This does not work in Skype for Business 16.0.4549.1000 32-bit on Windows 7 Pro SP1 (6.1.7601.65536)

Comment: Working on Skype version 8.63.0.76 (Mac)

Comment: This has stopped working since a few months back in Skype for linux. `{code}` and ``` works though

Comment: @nesono Fix your answer.

Answer (score 76):

New skype has a feature to add code. Try this

```
{code}
call_function(0);
:)
(smoke)
{code}
```

Comment: Could you please qualify *new* with a concrete version number?

Comment: It works here. Skype 7.1.0.105

Comment: This do not work with web skype at this time

Comment: Does not work on Skype Linux 4.3.0.37.

Comment: Does not work with Skype for Linux Beta 5.4.0.1 and xml

Comment: This does not work in Skype for Business 16.0.4549.1000 32-bit on Windows 7 Pro SP1 (6.1.7601.65536)

Comment: This breaks in new coloured Skype v8.10.0.4 when using multiple code blocks in between normal text in one message. Ending tag doesn't seem to apply anymore. Wheres markdown multiple-backticks like in the answer below seem to work fine now.

Comment: Working on Skype version 8.63.0.76 (Mac)

Comment: confirm. worked OK on Skype 8.69.0.77 under ubuntu20

Comment: Works, but still strips characters depending on what you are posting. The double bang '!!' (tho, it had limitations, too) didn't do this. Try this line for instance. `{code}
4562,xx@example.com,xx,randomtext!,example.com,USER,,1,[SMTP:user@example.com],1,0,400000,NULL,NULL,NULL
{code}` When MS makes things better they always make things worse. Ever notice that? If something works leave it. (Me yelling at the wind.)

Answer (score 33):

Markdown-like syntax also works. For example:

````
``` 
var s = "Block highlighting"; 
alert(s); 
```
````

Comment: I would say this is the best (fastest) way. `{code} {code}` and `<pre> </pre>` are longer to type and `<pre>` tags are stripped when the message is edited.

Comment: Currently this does not work

Comment: Does not work with Skype for Linux Beta 5.4.0.1 and xml

Comment: This does not work in Skype for Business 16.0.4549.1000 32-bit on Windows 7 Pro SP1 (6.1.7601.65536)

Comment: Does work for me in Skype 8.58.0.93 in Windows 10 LTSB 2016

Answer (score 3):

To get around this kind of problem in other chat systems, people often post the code fragment on a web-based snippet site like pastebin.com and then just send a link to the code via chat.

Comment: I know, like pastie.org, jsfiddle.net, codetidy.com, tinypaste.com, codepad.org, pastesite.com. This is not the point of the question.

Comment: Sorry, based on question "Can I somehow send text that will not be transformed?" I thought you were looking for a workaround.