# Sending text with formatting in Skype 6 and older

Tags: skype, html

It was possible to use html tags to format text in Skype before. As of version 5.8 that feature has been discontinued, but Skype still displays this text correctly if sent from an older version of a client that still allows this kind of formatting. This suggests that there is probably a way to send this kind of text without using  those old versions of clients that have performance issues on Windows 8.

Is there any extension/add-on/application or any other way to send these messages now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have ran in the same problem as you, I am with Martin here - I have not seen any good add-on that would do that for you.

However, I came up with a solution of my own. More of an work around here. It is quite simple really.

You must run multiple versions of Skype, as [described here.](http://community.skype.com/t5/General-Discussion/Searching-for-a-person-in-a-specific-country/m-p/178200#M1472)

After that, the next step would be running multiple instances of skype, [as described here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa829/how-can-i-run-two-skype-accounts-on-the-same-computer).

What goes for the performance issues - I just put the oldest version in offline mode (not logging out) when I am not using it and turn of any performance affecting options and notifications in settings. It helped me, but it should be tested on low-performance PCs. Then again, these kind of actions are not what low performance PC's are actually made for.

Answer (score 3):

New Skype (Skype for Windows 6.20.64.104) support basic text formating:

- `*bold*`
- `_italic_`
- `~strikethrough~`
- Preformatted text: use two exclamation marks as the first line (rest empty) and paste your snippet afterward (source https://superuser.com/a/806164/64719)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Skype have blitzed this entirely even Messenger Plus! (which was an awesome addon for WLMessenger) can't do it.

Looks like, as it was with the Model-T Ford, you can have your text in any colour you like... As long as it's black....

HTML formatting has been slashed as well, so you're out of luck there. Sorry :-/

Answer (score 0):

This feature been removed from Skype for the time being. It's not available in any newer public available client.

*(Disclaimer: I work for Skype)*

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but I believe that worth mentioning:

It is possible to copy a formated text from a symbol generator service like [fsymbols](http://fsymbols.com/generators/strikethrough/) and paste it directly into skype. It is not as good as having a second instance of Skype running but might be more practical.

Answer (score -1):

I just combine all known issues about text formatting in the Skype chat on my blog here http://www.peshkov.biz/2015/05/how-to-format-text-in-skype.html

Comment: Welcome, but unfortunately that's not how this site works. We need answers, not just external references. Could you add some key points that answer the question? (Same [here](http://superuser.com/questions/280264/send-preformatted-text-in-skype/916671#916671).)

Comment: Hello, so I should copy my post as plain text to this site?

Comment: We do [support formatting](http://superuser.com/help/formatting). And the keypoints that answer the question would suffice; anything else is in fact just noise.

Comment: Does it even apply to Skype 6 and older?

Comment: Yes, it could be apply