# Is it possible to make text strikethrough while sending instant messaging in skype?

Tags: skype, text-formatting

does any one know, whether or not it is possible to strike through text like  <s>this</s>  in skype while sending instant messaging or edit message which has been already sent.

I searched a little, and I found this [thread](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Is-there-a-way-to-strike-trough-the-text/td-p/5610). but it didn't help, plz see below image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. +0. Reasonable question. But: What Google searches have you already tried? Also, please modify your question's a title so that it forms a valid question and ends with a question mark. And please modify your question so that it doesn't ask "how do I", but so that it asks "How likely is it that it's possible to do this?" Then ask me to vote your question up.

Comment: @unforgettableid question and its title has been edited. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Still, please modify your question so that it doesn't ask "how do I", but so that it asks "How likely is it that it's possible to do this?"

Comment: I don't think Skype supports that kind of formatting

Comment: but the link which I have shared, is belongs to skype community, I dont understand how do they do it ?

Comment: What version of skype are you using?

Comment: @Raystafarian Its version is 6.6.0.106. just updated today morning.

Comment: @Aman that link is from 2 years ago. I'm pretty sure when MS merged messenger with skype, this functionality was deprecated.

Comment: [source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles) it doesn't exist as an option

Comment: @Raystafarian hmmm may be you are right... :) anyway I think we need to wait, till microsoft draw his attention to this thread.. :) Thank you

Comment: I see you have edited the question. Much better. +1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Now, it is **currently** possible in both Mac and Windows. Using `~` tildes surrounding text will make it <s>strikethrough</s>:

```
~this will strike-through~
```

[source - mac v7 & windows preview](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/10/16/instant-message-formatting-with-skype-for-mac-7-0)

Comment: Does not work in `Skype for Business`.

Comment: @SerG if Skype for Business is different than Skype, you may find another question or even post a question looking for a solution - pointing out that this one didn't work.

Comment: @Raystafarian My comment could save some time for those who looking for a solution working with SfB. It's not a reproof.

Comment: @SerG if you have a solution to SfB you can post a question/answer and link to it from here.

Answer (score 7):

While you can't do it quickly, you could use an online website to generate the text. Then you could copy and paste it in.

For example: http://fsymbols.com/generators/strikethrough/

Comment: Just keep in mind that stuff like that won't necessarily work, based on the available characters in the font being used.

Comment: Well it worked for me, though it looks abit shifty. But surely it would be fine enough

Comment: Looks perfect to me, and it's good enough for the 1 in a million times I make a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

<s>No, it's not **currently** possible. [source](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10042/what-are-chat-commands-and-roles)</s>

### Edit

See [new accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/832248/116196) above.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to use a few commands but got this as the answer from Skype **[09:30:05 PM] System: Available commands:
 /me [text]
 /add [skypename+]
 /alertson [text]
 /alertsoff
 /help**  Why is it that I cannot use all the commands listed in your source??

Answer (score 3):

Some Skype clients support this:
~strike~
Its depending on the client though.

Comment: Check also http://superuser.com/a/806164/64719