# How to send strikethrough text in Skype for Business?

Tags: fonts, skype-for-business

I'm trying to send a message with strikethrough text in it, and came across [this question and its answers](https://superuser.com/questions/621627/is-it-possible-to-make-text-strikethrough-while-sending-instant-messaging-in-sky), but it doesn't seem to work for Skype for Business.

I've tried:

~text~

The keyboard shortcuts page on the [Microsoft website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-skype-for-business-74eda765-5631-4fc1-8aad-cc870115347a) only seems to list italics, bold and underline, and the options under "Change font..." only list those three.

> Ctrl+B
> Make the selected text bold.
>
> Ctrl+l Italicize the selected text.
>
> Ctrl+U Underline the selected text.

Currently, the only thing that seems to work is creating strikethrough text in another application (e.g. Microsoft Word) and pasting it into SfB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't from what I have seen. One way as a workaround is to go into an application that can, such as Word, and then copy the text as strike-through from that application into the Skype box. It will retain formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Bookend your text with ~tildes~ to put a line through it. You might use this to convey sarcasm or show what's changed, for example.

Sample IM text with strikethrough

source: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34696/how-do-i-format-text-in-skype-instant-messages

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work in Skype for Business.